# Change ASP.NET Membership tables in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I have my own database (SQL Server 2008 RQ) and i have a table name "Users"
I wanna use ASP.NET MemberShip with my table (Users) how can i do this ?

I don't want to use normal DataBase, i wanna change tables and fields because i want to personalize it.

I don't want to use Profile, i want to change tables and fields, i know i can create my own authentication system but i want to use Login Control from ToolBox and other Controls.

Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy. You just have to create your own class inheriting from `MembershipProvider` and register it as a default provider. One of its methods in particular is designed to validate users' credentials. The builtin `Login` will use your own code, as long as you register your provider.

```
public class MyCustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider {
   // a lot of methods required by the abstract class

   public bool ValidateUser( string UserName, string Password ) {
      // use your own database to validate user credentials
   }
}
```

and then

```
<system.web>
   <membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
         <add name="MyCustomMembershipProvider" type="MyCustomMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
   </membership>
```

In case of any doubts, follow the example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a [custom MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) to use your own database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom membership provider; see this:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers